# Spring runnable jar to run on window

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I have created a project which was develop as a spring mvn project on eclipse but later had to add more jars which were not added though mvn , So i collected all the jar in a folder and created a runnable jar thru eclipse and try to run from command prompt ,it is showing below error and it is running in eclipse :

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.
StandardEnvironment).`enter code here`
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinit
ionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHan
dler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.err
or(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Spring Boot to avoid this problem. Creating a runnable jar with Spring is a headache mainly because of the overlapping `spring.schemas` and `spring.handler` files (which are responsible for finding the `NamespaceHandlers`). Maven will overwrite these files when you build to a single jar.

But for now, you can take a look at the [Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) and using [ResourceTransformers](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html)

> Aggregating classes/resources from several artifacts into one uber JAR is straight forward as long as there is no overlap. Otherwise, some kind of logic to merge resources from several JARs is required. This is where resource transformers kick in.

Code from Shade plugin site (followed by comments)

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                  <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

> Some jars contain additional resources (such as properties files) that have the same file name. To avoid overwriting, you can opt to merge them by appending their content into one file. One good example for this is when aggregating both the spring-context and plexus-spring jars. Both of them have the `META-INF/spring.handlers` file which is used by Spring to handle XML schema namespaces. You can merge the contents of all the files with that specific name using the `AppendingTransformer`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring Boot fits well here.

I wrote some tutorials about Spring Boot.

Start with the following:

- [Spring Boot: Persistence & Transaction](http://manueljordanelera.blogspot.com/2014/06/springbootpersistencetransaction.html)